# Cálculo da média em php

Tags: php, sql

Preciso calcular a média final das notas de alunos de uma turma, tentei usando a função `avg` do SQL, mas não obtive sucesso, o código é esse:

```
<?php
    $idTurma = $_GET["idTurma"];
    $idDisciplina = $_GET["idDisciplina"];

    include ("conectar.php");

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.nome, n.faltas1, n.faltas2, n.sem1, n.sem2, a.idaluno, d.iddisciplina from aluno a, nota n, turma t, disciplina d where t.idturma=$idTurma and a.idturma=t.idturma and n.iddisciplina=$idDisciplina and d.iddisciplina=n.iddisciplina and n.idaluno=a.idaluno");
    $linha = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($linha) {
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr align=center>";
    echo "<td rowspan=2>Alunos</td>";
    echo "<td colspan=2>1º SEM</td>";
    echo "<td colspan=2>2º SEM</td>";
    echo "<td rowspan=2>Média Final</td>";
    echo "<td rowspan=2>Editar</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr align=center>";
    echo "<td>Nota</td>";
    echo "<td>Faltas</td>";
    echo "<td>Nota</td>";
    echo "<td>Faltas</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $nome = $dados['nome'];
    $sem1 = $dados['sem1'];
    $faltas1 = $dados['faltas1'];
    $sem2 = $dados['sem2'];
    $faltas2 = $dados['faltas2'];

    $idDisciplina = $dados  ['iddisciplina'];
    $idAluno = $dados ['idaluno'];
    echo "<tr align=center>";
    echo "<td>".$nome."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$sem1."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$faltas1."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$sem2."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$faltas2."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$mediafinal."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='editarnota.php?idAluno=$idAluno&idDisciplina=$idDisciplina'><img src='images/editar.gif'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código com a função "avg" que você tentou?

Comment: select avg(sem1), (sem2) from nota where idaluno=2(exemplo), na tabela nota também tem campo de faltas, então não sei como pegar dois valores e fazer a média, a média final não fica salva no banco, apenas é mostrada na tabela com o resultado do php

Comment: preciso de ajuda tanto no código sql, quanto no php para pegar as variáveis e mostrar na tabela :(

Comment: Como é a estrutura da sua tabela `nota`?

Comment: idaluno, iddisciplina, sem1, sem1, faltas1 e faltas2

Comment: Como você tem 2 notas em uma linha, a função AVG não vai trazer o resultado esperado, pois ela faz a média de um campo com base em todos os registros retornados da consulta.

Comment: Pra fazer a média, seria algo como `SELECT ((sem1+sem2)/2) AS media FROM nota WHERE idaluno = 2`

Comment: obrigada, e como eu faria pra armazenar esse resultado em uma variável e depois mostrar na tabela?

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque não demonstrou esforço do autor na solução do problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você tem 2 notas em uma linha, a função `AVG` não vai trazer o resultado esperado, pois ela faz a média de um campo com base em todos os registros retornados da consulta.
Para tirar a média, vai ter que somar o conteúdo dos 2 campos e dividir por 2.

```
<?php
$idTurma = $_GET["idTurma"];
$idDisciplina = $_GET["idDisciplina"];

include ("conectar.php");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT
    a.nome,
    n.faltas1,
    n.faltas2,
    ((n.sem1 + n.sem2) / 2) AS media_final,
    a.idaluno,
    d.iddisciplina
FROM
    aluno a,
    nota n,
    turma t,
    disciplina d
WHERE
    t.idturma = $idTurma
AND a.idturma = t.idturma
AND n.iddisciplina = $idDisciplina
AND d.iddisciplina = n.iddisciplina
AND n.idaluno = a.idaluno");

$linha = mysql_num_rows($result); 

if ($linha) {
    echo "<table border=1>
         <tr align=center>
         <td rowspan=2>Alunos</td>
         <td colspan=2>1º SEM</td>
         <td colspan=2>2º SEM</td>
         <td rowspan=2>Média Final</td>
         <td rowspan=2>Editar</td>
         </tr>
         <tr align=center>
         <td>Nota</td>
         <td>Faltas</td>
         <td>Nota</td>
         <td>Faltas</td>
         </tr>";

    while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ //use a constante MYSQL_ASSOC para poder usar a array com os aliases da query
        $nome = $dados['nome'];
        $sem1 = $dados['sem1'];
        $faltas1 = $dados['faltas1'];
        $sem2 = $dados['sem2'];
        $faltas2 = $dados['faltas2'];
        //agora para pegar a média, é só acessar o alias media_final, que temos na query e que está presente em $dados
        $mediafinal = $dados['media_final'];

        $idDisciplina = $dados  ['iddisciplina'];
        $idAluno = $dados ['idaluno'];
        echo "<tr align=center>
        <td>{$nome}</td>
        <td>{$sem1}</td>
        <td>{$faltas1}</td>
        <td>{$sem2}</td>
        <td>{$faltas2}</td>
        <td>{$mediafinal}</td>
        <td><a href='editarnota.php?idAluno={$idAluno}&idDisciplina={$idDisciplina}'><img src='images/editar.gif'></td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: sensacional, muito obrigada!!!!

Comment: Se funcionou, não esqueça de sinalizar a resposta como correta. Se ajudou você, vai ajudar os demais com a mesma dúvida.